# how can I pause a docker container running luigi?

Tags: docker, luigi

I have a docker container running a 10 hour luigi task. I want to pause the container to use my laptop for something else. I tried "docker pause" but when I unpause the luigi scheduler shows no tasks running. So I have to start again.

Is there any way I can pause and restart exactly where I left off? I suspect it may be luigi that is deleting the task.

Comment: Maybe mount luigi file to host can fix the problem.